# MySQL DAYOFMONTH() Not Working

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, sum

With this  SQL query,

```
SELECT SUM( Views ) 
FROM  `pages_analytics` 
WHERE (
ID
IN ( 60, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 174, 175 ) 
AND TIME = DAYOFMONTH(  '2013-12-07' )
)
```

I am unable to get a sum. The `TIME` table is a timestamp, and each row is a few seconds different from each other, but has the same day. What am I doing wrong? I am currently getting an output of `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in an **index-friendly** way

```
SELECT SUM(views) total_views
  FROM  pages_analytics
 WHERE id IN (60, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 174, 175) 
   AND time >= '2013-12-07'
   AND time <  '2013-12-08'
```

**Note:** Using `DAYOFMONTH()` or any other function for that matter will **prevent** MySQL from possibly using any index you might have on `time` column effectively causing full scan each time you query your data.

Recommended reading:

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) by @AaronBertrand

Comment: Few databases use an index on a `time` column for a range query.  The number of lookups required is too expensive.

Comment: @Andomar the datatype of `time` column is `timestamp`.